# change only one property of location search object

Tags: angularjs

According to [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) one can set search parameters on the location as follows:

```
$location.search({a: 'b', c: true});
```

to get location as this:

```
http://example.com/base/index.html#!/foo?a=b&c
```

Let say I already have some search parameters on current location. What would be simplest and neat approach to change only one parameter and not to override others?

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the actual `$location.search()` parameters and [extend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) it with your new search params.

For example:

```
var
    currentSearch = $location.search(),
    myNewSearch = { a: 'd' };

angular.extend(myNewSearch , currentSearch );

$location.search(myNewSearch);
```